# Broadcasting less-than filtering in NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Given two arrays `a` and `b`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10, dtype=float)    
b = np.arange(0, 10, 2, dtype=float)
```

I would like to return an array `c` that is the same shape as `b`, for which each element in `c` equals the mean of `a`, conditional on that `a` is less than the corresponding element of `b`.  That is a mouthful and much easier to express as:

```
c = np.array([a[a <= i].mean() for i in b])
```

But is there any way to avoid list comprhension here?  Using just `b` rather than `i` throws a `ValueError` because the two cannot be broadcast.

Note: as I have things now, `a` is not (necessarily) sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow for [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we need to add in a new axis for one of the input arrays. Adding in for `a`, here's one solution -

```
mask = (a[:,None] <= b)
c = a.dot(mask)/mask.sum(0)
```

Basically, `a.dot(mask)` gets us the summations and we are dividing it by the number of valid elements, found out with `mask.sum(0)` to get the equivalent of averaging.